# Bulk insert into DB with Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I've seen on SO that you can do multiple inserts without having to do them in a loop, with the `createRowset` and `createRow` methods.

My problem is, that I'm not sure in which class the `createRowset` method is defined. I have the following code, which fails with an 500 internal error:

```
$twitterUsersModel = new TwitterUsers($this->db_adapter);
$rowset = $twitterUsersModel->createRowset(); // this is the line that fails
foreach ($data as $d) 
{
    $row = $twitterUsersModel->createRow($d);
    $rowset->addRow($row);
}
$rowset->save();
```

My `TwitterUsers` class extends the `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` class, which (as far as I can tell) doesn't have a `createRowset` method (just tested with extending `Zend_Db_Table`, still not working). Is there any other way to do this from a `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` extending class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its defined nowhere actually. This feature is not yet implemented in Zend framework. However this is proposed as a new feature in Zend Framework Issue tracker.

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2322

Vote for it, to get the feature sooner.

Comment: I see, so I'll have to do my inserts in a loop afterall :( just sad that it doesn't offer this kind of stuff. Thank you!